# What is the Right Setting to Receive Push Notification

Tags: streaming-api

So I have a VF page with Streaming API and it's working fine in me because I'm the System Administrator. Now I'm testing out as another user with different profile, and the Streaming API is not working for this user.

This is what I enabled In user's Profile:

```
Object
PushTopic
Read  -  true
```

---

And also The Custom Object I'm Streaming

```
Enable Streaming API - true
```

---

And of course I enabled the Streaming API for my ORGANISATION.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Does the other user's profile has access to the object that you're subscribing to? Also check the field level security for the fields that you're listening for a change

Comment: Ok I'll try what you've said.

Comment: Oh great!! A lot of thanks to you!!! I'm ashamed that I didn't check that before asking questions here.

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer, so i can mark it as answer to my question. Thanks again @Bachovski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely the field level security for the fields that you're listening for a change or permissions for the object that you're subscribing for in your query for that particular user's profile.

These are the things you should look out for every time you experience an issue when switching between profiles.